# SelectTokens with specific c#

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

In the process I do using the 'Where' method below, I reach the list named 'list1' in the json.
I need to do the same operation without using the 'Where' method, only using 'SelectTokens' once.

When I try this(test2) I am only accessing the last item.

```
var test = jsonVal.SelectTokens("data.list1[*]").Where(x => x.SelectTokens("list2[?(@.value > 15)]").Count() != 0);

var test2 = jsonVal.SelectTokens($"data.list1[*].list2[?(@.value > 15)]");
```

ex json:

```
{
    "data": {
        "list1": [
            {
                "list2": [
                    {
                        "value": 20
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "list2": [
                    {
                        "value": 10
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note: JSON can be confusing. Basically what I want is to be able to pass a specific part of my query into a variable.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oxNyaL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **nested filter expressions** to select all entries of `list1` that have at least one matching entry of `list2` like so:

```
var items = jsonVal.SelectTokens("data.list1[?(@.list2[?(@.value > 15)])]");
```

The returned items, when serialized, match the contents of `test` as required:

```json
[
  {
    "list2": [
      {
        "value": 20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Notes:

- The inner expression `list2[?(@.value > 15)]` selects all entries of list2 with value > 15.
- The outer expression `data.list1[?(@list2 query)]` selects all entries in list1 that have matching entries in list2.
- I'm not sure that nested filter expressions work on all JSONPath implementations.  If I try the above query + JSON on https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/, neither Stefan Goessner's JSONPath 0.8.3 nor Flow Communications's JSONPath 0.5.0 can evaluate the query.

  The [JSONPath proposal](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath) merely states that `?()` should applies a filter (script) expression "using the underlying script engine" which is quite ambiguous.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QnUpIv).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. Wishing you happiness...